# Application name size limitation

Tags: android, icons, google-play

I'd like to give my application a name that is more than 20 characters long. The complete name should be displayed and it must be visible in the home screen below the App icon.Google however restricts such a long name. Is this possible at all? What is the maximum length in this case? I've seen applications display more than 15 characters.

Comment: It's a system thing. All be depends of screen size. Larger icon - large text limit size.